# Oracle sql: if I am doing a comparison operator on a date field do i still need a not null

Tags: sql, oracle

If I am doing a comparison operator (>, <, =) on a date field do I also need a IS NOT NULL on the date field

Comment: What are logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference what datatype it is. If you want to check whether something is equal to, less than or greater than something else then it can't really be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then no - you don't have to check whether it is not null.

For example (today is `date '2022-07-07'`, 7th of July 2022):

```
SQL> with test (id, date_column) as
  2    (select 1, date '2022-05-25' from dual union all  -- before today
  3     select 2, date '2022-12-13' from dual union all  -- after today
  4     select 3, null              from dual            -- unknown, as there's no value in DATE_COLUMN
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where date_column >= sysdate;

        ID DATE_COLUM
---------- ----------
         2 2022-12-13

SQL>
```

If you include the `not null` check, you'll get the same result:

```
<snip>
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where date_column is not null
  9    and date_column >= sysdate;

        ID DATE_COLUM
---------- ----------
         2 2022-12-13

SQL>
```

Comment: yes I got the same result I just wanted to double check to be sure thanks